# How can I plot bollinger bands on financial time series?

Tags: finance, charts

I can't find any options for this in `CandlestickChart[]`, but it's a pretty basic measure, is it not supported?

Comment: Use `TradingChart`, specify `BollingerBands` as an indicator...

Comment: Well, @ciao beat me to it. Let me just add a link to the documentation for  [`BollingerBands`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/indicator/BollingerBands.html#)

Answer (score 4):

```
TradingChart[{"GOOG", {"Jan 1, 2015", "Apr 30, 2015"}}, 
 FinancialIndicator["BollingerBands"], 
 PlotLabel -> "Google Stock Price \[LongDash] 2015"]
```

[image]

You can alter the paramters, e.g, `FinancialIndicator["BollingerBands", blah, yada]`

Comment: …the default setting being `FinancialIndicator["BollingerBands", 20, 2]`.